# is Touch is same as click when we our finger leave the screen

Tags: android

I have someText , which exceeds screen length . i have also added , Action_bar in the same Activity .

what i want : whenever i `Use_click_event` in `Action_bar_item` , my `Action_bar_hides` So now i have `only_text` in my `View` and again if you click in the Screen you will `get_back Action_bar` in a `View` .

what is happening : `after_hiding Action_bar` , when ever i am scrolling : text is scrolling 
but just after `leaving the screen` ( finger is leaving screen ) `Action_bar` is taking it place

basically i want to get_back `Action_bar` `when ever i am clicking` `not when i am leaving the touch_mode` .

My code is :

```
public void onResume ( )
{
    super.onResume();

    View view = findViewById(R.id.layout) ;

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if ( !getActionBar().isShowing() )
            {
                getActionBar().show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't really clear.

Comment: Your question is still not clear..what do you really want? to toggle the visibility of the action bar? Can you exactly define at what events do you want to hide it and at what event you want to show the action bar again?